# Swipe gesture is not being called on a subview inside a present view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, xcode11.3

I presented a view controller and I have a subview in it. I added a swipe gesture on the subview. The swipe gesture is not being called. Instead, the presented view controller is trying to dismiss itself i.e. going down. How do I override the swipe gesture to be recognised by the subview instead of the super view. 
When I implemented swipe on a static view controller, it works as expected.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewSwipe: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeUp(_:)))
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
        self.viewSwipe.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

        let swipedown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeDown(_:)))
        swipedown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down
        self.viewSwipe.addGestureRecognizer(swipedown)
    }

    @objc func swipeUp(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print("swiped up")
    }

    @objc func swipeDown(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print("swiped down")
    }
}
```

The red area needs to get swipe

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do you presenting this smaller view controller?

Comment: No smaller view is not presented. The bigger view containing this smaller view is presented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Gesture` only in view and you can also add any direction on gesture. Here i put Small example, you can refer this code for your problem.

**Get 1 for Right Direction and 2 For Left Direction**

**Example :**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

 @IBOutlet weak var viewGray: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var viewRed: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

   self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self

   let directions: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction] = [.right, .left]
     for direction in directions {
        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        gesture.direction = direction
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.viewRed.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
     }
  }

  @objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.direction)
  }

   func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return true
   }

  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      return true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works but it doesn't work when super view was presented modally on part of screen

Comment: Yes you are right it's not work but I Solve it and update my answer, Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work. If not there, is probably conflict with different gesture recognizer. To solve this conflict, you can set `delegate` on your `swipeUp` and `swipeDown` recognizers:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate 

swipeUp.delegate = self
swipeDown.delegate = self
```

and try to investigate what is happening in this delegate funcs (with breakpoints or with print, it is up to you):

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

If none of this delegate funcs is called, when you are trying to swipe. Then there is probably different (ie invisible) view over you content.

Comment: Hey. I got the callbacks in the gesture recognizers. I did see my added gesture action in there as well as the other _UISheetInteractionBackgroundDismissRecognizer. Will invest time on this.

Answer (score 0):

you code will work. Just try to present your view controller as a full screen in case iOS 13. Refer following code.

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: No I don't want to present on fullscreen.